# How to add a dynamic variable value inside a param field as a String in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have an API, wherein the Param field, I need to pass the current date as a string.

```
And param filter = 'ORDER_DATE:"2021-01-31"'
```

I am trying to pass the current date for the ORDER_DATE field form a java method:

```
* def todaysDate = helper.getTodaysDate()

And print todaysDate // Prints 2021-02-04
```

Now I need to pass this "todaysDate " valuein the param filter field.

Following what I have tried so far:

```
And param filter = 'ORDER_DATE:#(todaysDate )' 
And param filter = 'ORDER_DATE:<todaysDate>'
```

From example table value.

In Both cases, it printed "todaysDate " instead of its value "2021-02-04"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just JavaScript:

```
And param filter = 'ORDER_DATE:"' + todaysDate + '"'
```

This can improve in the [1.0 version](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide) BTW:

```
And param filter = `ORDER_DATE:"${todaysDate}"`
```

Further reading: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

Comment: Great.. eagerly waiting for the latest release.